# Show that a space curve lies entirely on a plane.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

If we have a vector function $r(t) = (4\cos t-1, 6-5\sin t, -3\cos t+1)$, how can I show that it lies entirely on a plane? The only thing I can think of doing is checking if the bi-normal vector $B(t) =  T(t) \times N(t)$ is constant. I'm not really sure if my reasoning is correct and it's difficult to word but ill give it a go:

The bi-normal vector is orthogonal to both $T(t)$ and N(t)$ so if this points in the same direction regardless of where we are on the curve, we have the bi-normal vector being the vector orthogonal to the plane in which the curve lies.

Is there an easier way to do this? Because computing the bi-normal vector is quite a long process. Thanks.

Comment: This curve does not lie on a plane.

Comment: It's not on a plane: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+parametric+plot+%28t%5E2%2Csin%282t%29%2Ccos%282t%29%29+fot+t%3D0+to+2pi

Comment: But if I had another curve, that is on a plane, how would I show it?

Comment: I have edited the question with a curve that does lie on a plane.

Comment: Hint :prove that for any three points $A,B,C$ on the curve,  $A-B$, $A-C$, $B-C$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of get why this would work. But is there a more calculus(ish) way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Frenet-Serret relations. Compute Torsion. Necessary/sufficient condition for a space curve to be in a plane is that torsion must vanish.

Answer (score 0):

$r(t)$ equals an affine function of $(\cos t, \sin t)$. The curve thus lies in the image of an affine function $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.